# Emulator failed to start

Tags: android

When i try to launch an emulator based on system image Android 4.4 armeabi-v7a (because my system does not support virtualization) in Android Studio, it starts and fades away within 2-3 seconds and the status bar shows "Starting device".
When i try to start it through cmd by going to the path "C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools" and using the command "emulator -avd AVD_NAME -memory 768 -no-accel -gpu on" the following error comes: [Error while starting emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvRRM.png)

Please help.

Answer (score -1):

Have you try to open your bios setting  and enable virtualization there?

If virtualization is not in pc then you can install zenymotion in the system

Comment: There is no option in my bios to "enable virtualization". Cant I run this Inbuilt Emulator otherwise i have to buy it.

Comment: Isn't it priced

Comment: and also its hardware requirements says "64 bit CPU, with VT-x or AMD-V capability, enabled in BIOS settings"